# Unsuccessful attempt to start minecraft server on amazon hosting

Tags: server, binding, port, minecraft

I'm tried to start minecraft server on not custom port (25565 for example) with command:

*java -jar craftbukkit.jar*

but had an exception java.net.BindException:

---

Loading libraries, please wait...

[12:24:27 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.7.2

[12:24:27 WARN]: To start the server with more ram, launch it as "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar"

[12:24:27 INFO]: Loading properties

[12:24:27 INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL

[12:24:27 INFO]: Generating keypair

[12:24:28 INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on 52.25.177.236:25565

[12:24:28 WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!

[12:24:28 WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

[12:24:28 WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?

---

After that I tried to stop all processes on this port with command:

*fuser -k 25565/tcp
fuser -k 25565/tcp*

but it didn't help too.

After that I tried to enable this port in iptables with commands:

---

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT

---

but it didn't help too.

Then I seen ifconfig and noticed that indet addr because it is not public ip, with whitch I work through ssh, it is hidden ip of internal network in amazon.

---

eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:89:4f:57:67:9d
inet addr:172.31.29.204  Bcast:172.31.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0

---

This ip I can set when I create new hosting in amazon. But I can't choose public ip when I do it.
Can someone exlain what is this hidden ip address and can be trouble with I start minecraft server on public ip but eth0 interface show me only hidden internal?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that someone on the same machine is using port 25565. I would recommend contacting amazon and resolving it with them